# Combinations Counting subsets

Tags: combinations

Given the set A=(-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6)

In how many ways can you select four different numbers so that their product is negative? Explain your soulution

Comment: Hint: One negative or three negative, the rest positive.

Comment: I do not understand the hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of four non-zero numbers is negative precisely if one of the numbers is negative or three of the numbers are negative.

One negative: The negative number can be chosen in $\binom{6}{1}$ ways, and the three positives that keep it company can then be chosen in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{6}{1}\binom{6}{3}$.

Three negative: It's your turn.

Finally, add.

Comment: So I would add 6C1 and 6C3 is that what your saying?

Comment: The final answer will be $\binom{6}{1}\binom{6}{3}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{6}{1}$, presumably calculated out.  In my answer, nowhere did it say to add $\binom{6}{1}$ and $\binom{6}{3}$.

Comment: So the Final answer is 240

Comment: Yes, it is $240$. But the key thing is understanding the reasoning.

Comment: You are welcome.